# Finding a register by field

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have my database in firebase as you can see here  https://snag.gy/bhopOk.jpg

The user scans a product and brings you the number of this product, which is put in an input, then when you click on search you must bring the description and the value of that item and show it somewhere in the front
[This is my frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1L4u.png)

How would the function or query be so that when the person click on search brings me the requested data? I know it's a simple query but I do not have it very clear I'm new to ionic

I tried to do this to see if I returned something in the console but nothing

```
findproduct(){
   var ref = firebase.database().ref("/productos/");
ref.orderByChild("Producto").equalTo(1706).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function as follows. However, note that `query.once()` is asynchronous and returns a Promise. So you have to take that into account when you call it.

```
findproduct(productID) {
    var query = firebase.database().ref("productos").orderByChild("Producto").equalTo(productID);
    query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            console.log(childKey);
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(childData);
        });
    });
}
```

When you just want to query once, use the `once()` method: it "Listens for exactly one event of the specified event type ('alue' in this case), and then stops listening". See the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#once).

When using the `on()` method, you are **constantly** listening to data changes at the location defined by the query. See the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on).

Comment: mmm its a little clear right now thanks for answer , but if i want to put the variable that comes of my frontend instead of the number 1706 , how can i do it? because in that code i just put a static number please help me

Comment: I've updated my answer. However, note that `query.once()` **is asynchronous and returns a Promise**. So you have to take that in account when you call it.